# [ERLANG]: Why answer returns list in a list rather than list?

Tags: list, erlang, tuples

Given the module

```
-module(p1). 

-export([f2/2]). 

f2([A, A | B]) -> {A, B}; 
f2([A, B | _]) -> {A, B}; 
f2([A]) -> A; 
f2(_) -> no_match.
```

I was asked to try the input value

```
 p1:f2([1,1,[1,1]]).
```

My answer would be that this input value matches the first function clause of f2, and as such gives us the result:

```
{1,[1,1]}
```

But according to the given answer sheet, the answer is

```
{1,[[1,1]]}
```

I can't quite get my head around why we get a list within a list, rather than a list in the answer. Would appreciate an explanation for this, thank you.

Comment: Your code isn't compilable btw.

Comment: You are exporting `f2/2` and implementing `f2/1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into how head-tail works in Erlang.  Tail is always a list; could be a one element list, could be an empty list, but always a list.

Lets look into example in shell:

```
2> Fun = fun([H | T]) -> {H, T} end. 
#Fun<erl_eval.6.90072148>
3> Fun([a]).
{a,[]}
4> Fun([a,b]).
{a,[b]}
5> Fun([a,[a,b]]).
{a,[[a,b]]}
6> Fun([a,b,c]).  
{a,[b,c]}
7> Fun([a,b,c,d]).
{a,[b,c,d]}
```

So in you case what you are returning is `A` which is repeted `1` and `B` which is list of all remaining elements.  In our case only one element remains, so we return one-element list.  And this element is a two-element list, hence list in a list `[[1, 1]]`.

Comment: Thank you, it all makes sense now!

Comment: You could mark question as solved, if it in fact is.